# How do you make manifest.json for Microsoft Teams bot?

Tags: json, botframework, microsoft-teams

I followed the online tutorial for constructing a bot in Visual Studio and deploying it Azure, and so far that seems to have worked. Now I want to add this bot to Microsoft Teams via the "Sideload a bot or tab" method. The online tutorial has NO explanation for what I need to do so I need some help. Here is the manifest.json I was currently trying to upload in a zip folder. Please help, I don't know how this process works.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.0/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.0",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "a5db14e6-8adf-445b-a0aa-daadc5e155eb",
  "packageName": "com.testbot20170525114049",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Megan",
    "websiteUrl": "https://website.com/",
    "privacyUrl": "https://website.com/privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://website.com/app-tos"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Botty"
  }
  "description": {
    "short": "A sample bot to test the bot upload process"
  }
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "a5db14e6-8adf-445b-a0aa-daadc5e155eb",
      "needsChannelSelector":  "true",
      "scopes": [ "team", "personal" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: _"The online tutorial has NO explanation for what I need to do "_ - is that [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/setup#enable-sideloading-of-bots-and-tabs)?

Comment: Have you gone through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/sideload and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/createpackage ?

Answer (score 4):

1. [Enable Public Developer Preview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/publicpreview). The v1.0 manifest is fully supported in that mode, and while it may work in the public version, for now I'd switch to developer preview mode.
2. Make sure your manifest follows the [v1.0 format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/schema). While your schema is close, there are a few required fields missing:

   - description.full
   - icons.outline
   - icons.color (note currently there is a 2k limit on file size)
   - accentColor
3. Zip the manifest and icons into a [sideloadable package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/createpackage). Make sure the manifest.json is at the top level.
4. Follow the [sideload instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/sideload).